# random numbers in order + unique php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a random number generator which has the following features:

- Each one is unique
- Numbers are either 1 or 49 and all in between
- Ordered from lowest to highest

This is what I have so far

```
$numbers = rand(1, 49)." ".rand(1, 49)." ".rand(1, 49)." ".rand(1, 49)." ".rand(1, 49)." ".rand(1, 49);

echo "Your Lucky Lotto Numbers Are: ".$numbers;
```

Im just not quite sure how to go about ordering them, plus the numbers being unique.

Comment: Are you considering only integers?

Comment: Create an array of the numbers 1 to 49, pick N numbers from it randomly, put them in an array and sort that.

Comment: create an array to hold the numbers. With the array you can check if the number is already there and the can be orderd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create an array with all the numbers from 1 to 49, and start randomly removing elements. Leave only the number of elements you need. That way, they are already in order, and are definitely unique.

Example:

```
$values = range(1,49);

while(count($values)>6) {
  unset($values[array_rand($values)]);
}

print "Your results: ".implode(', ',$values);
```

Comment: This one works a charm. Thanks for this and to everyone else who posted. But this is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array for this:

```
$numbers = range(1, 49); //generate the array
shuffle($numbers); //shuffle the array
$numbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 6); // cut the array in the appopriate length

echo "Your Lucky Lotto Numbers Are: ";
print_r(asort($numbers)); //sort and print
```

Some useful literature:

- Arrays in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- Loop through array elements using `foreach`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- Sorting in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers = range(1, 49);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = array_slice($numbers, 0, 5);
sort($numbers);
foreach ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {
    echo $numbers[$i]." ";
}
```

[Range](http://php.net/range) & [Shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

Take an array with your numbers, take 6 random numbers (or shuffle array, pick first 6), sort your picked numbers. Not highly efficient, but should definitely work:

```
$numbers = range(1, 49);
shuffle($numbers);
$picks = array_slice($numbers, 0, 6);
sort($picks);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways how to do this:

**1) generate non-existing numbers**

You create array and add random numbers to it. If newly generated number already is in that array, generate another one (and so on until it is unique, check it in some while cycle), then sort it. i would recommend this

**2) increment for all existing lower numbers**

With each new random number, you lower the maximum by 1, then when adding this number, increment it for each lower number in you array

for example, when you have range 1-49 (inclusive) and numbers [4, 8, 6, 15], you generate number from 1-45 (inclusive), cause there are only 45 free numbers left. Lets say you generated 8, that means 8ht free number, and since 4, 8 and 6 are already there increment that three times and you got 11, however this requires your array to be sorted all the time.

**3) same as @hexblot said**

I would choose 1 cause its simple and you dont get much same selections if the amount of number is "lot" smaller then the number range (i.e. 5 numbers from 1-49 - 10% isnt much)

Answer (score 0):

a little extensive maybe, but this will give you 6 unique sorted numbers

```
$arr = array();
while ( count($arr) < 6 ) {
    $x = mt_rand(1,49);
    if ( !in_array($x,$arr) ) {
        $arr[] = $x;
        asort($arr);
    }
}
foreach($arr as $x){
        echo $x." ";
        }
```

Comment: sort after each adding? isnt that useless?